# Scala Play! form + dynamic routes

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework-2.0

As for now i had my url look like this: /chart?phrase=xxx

I wanted to prettify it, so i've created a route:

```
GET     /chart/:phrase          controllers.Application.chart(phrase: String)
```

Here's my old form:

```
@form(routes.Application.chart) {

    @inputText(tagForm("phrase"), 'placeholder -> "Phrase") 

    <input type="submit" value="Search for phrase">
}
```

But compiler returns errors about missing parameters in form(call). How can i make this work?

Please notice, that i'm using custom class "tagForm".

Answer (score 0):

change your url to

```
GET     /chart/:phrase          controllers.Application.chart(phrase: String)
```

and at your template

```
 routes.Application.chart("phraseValue")
```

now url looks like

```
/chart/pharseValue
```

Comment: I'm getting with this urls like: `/chart?phrase=value`. I want to simplify it to `/chart/value`.

Comment: @m.cichacz then you have to use `:pharse`

Comment: Then I'm getting `phraseValue?phrase=value`. Am I doing sth wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: It wasn't clear that you *didn't* want query parameters, so have a look at the **Reverse routing** section of the [Play Documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaRouting).

---

Query parameters aren't included in the route URI. There are two ways you can use them. One requires a default value, and the other uses an `Option`, depending on what suits your needs.

```
#  Defaults to an empty string if the query parameter is not in the URL.
GET     /chart         controllers.Application.chart(phrase: String ?= "")

#  Defaults to `None` if the query parameter is not in the URL.
GET     /chart          controllers.Application.chart(phrase: Option[String])
```

The reverse routes would work as such:

```
// Routes with default values
routes.Application.chart("test")    // Outputs /chart?phrase=test
routes.Application.chart()    // Outputs /chart

// Routes using `Option`
routes.Application.chart(Some("test"))    // Outputs /chart?phrase=test
routes.Application.chart(None)    // Outputs /chart
```

Comment: sorry about not being clear enough. Unfortunately **Reverse routing** section doesn't fully answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution. Maybe it's not perfect, but suits my needs.

To have pretty URLs when submitting a form I created two Routes:

```
GET     /chart/:phrase          controllers.Application.chart(phrase: String)
GET     /getResult              controllers.Application.getResult
```

And two Actions:

```
def chart(query: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    tagForm.bind(Map("phrase"->query)).fold(error,success)
}

def getResult = Action { implicit request =>
tagForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  errors => BadRequest(...),
    req => {
      ...
      Redirect(routes.Application.chart(string))
    }
  )
}
```

And in form: `@form(routes.Application.getResult)`

Form submits tagForm to getResult, where after validation it redirects to pretty url.

Comment: Is it really worth it to write a whole new function to save yourself one word in the view? Redirecting like this is considered bad practice, and furthermore the extra code needed to make this work will grow exponentially with your `Form`. Please don't do this.